# AWS amplify remember logged in user in React Native app

Tags: react-native, authentication, aws-amplify

I just started exploring AWS amplify as a backend for my react native application. Being a true beginner on using the service, I want my app to remember the logged in user every time I refresh the emulator.

I know from AWS amplify documentation that I can use the Auth function **currentAuthenticatedUser** for this purpose, but I have no idea on how to implement a code that does this purpose.

My app looks like this:

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import AuthTabs from './components/AuthTabs';
import NavigationTab from './components/NavigationTab';

import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import AWSConfig from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(AWSConfig);

export default class App extends React.Component {
   state = {
   isAuthenticated: false
}

authenticate(isAuthenticated) {
   this.setState({ isAuthenticated })
}

render() {
  if (this.state.isAuthenticated) {
    console.log('Hello', Auth.user.username)
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
          Hello {Auth.user.username}!
        </Text>
        <NavigationTab
          screenProps={
            {authenticate: this.authenticate.bind(this)}
          }
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <AuthTabs
      screenProps={
        {authenticate: this.authenticate.bind(this)}
      }
    />
    </View>
  )
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also have come up with a similar solution. But instead of the constructor, I use the life cycle method ***componentDidMount()*** to call a method that I named ***loadApp()***.

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native'

import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth'

export default class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    userToken: null
  }
  async componentDidMount () {
    await this.loadApp()
  }
  // Get the logged in users and remember them
  loadApp = async () => {
    await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
    .then(user => {
      this.setState({userToken: user.signInUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken})
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    this.props.navigation.navigate(this.state.userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth')
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#fff" />
      </View>     
    )
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#aa73b7',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
})
```

***loadApp()*** will try and get the user JWT Token by calling the AWS Amplify ***currentAuthenticatedUser()*** method. The obtained token is then stored in the component *state*.

I have used **[React navigation version 2](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/2.x/getting-started.html)** to navigate the user to either the App screen or the Auth stack screen depending on her status: logged in or not logged in.

Answer (score 3):

i have used it like this:

```
currentUser = () => {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then(user => {
        console.log("USER", user);
        this.props.navigation.navigate("App");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("ERROR", err);
      });
  };
```

so, one can call it on the constructor on app refresh, and if the user is authenticated go to the main screen, but if it's not, stay in the login screen. Cheers.

Comment: I get `not authenticated` when calling `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()`. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at the docs, "This method should be called after the Auth module is configured or the user is logged in" this may be the problem, but it is hard to tell without code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I handled this issue:

```
const currentUserInfo = await Auth.currentUserInfo()

if (currentUserInfo){
  const data = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
  dispatch({authTypes.FETCH_USER_DATA_SUCCESS, {payload: {user: data}}});
}
```